# Linux How To Take From X arg to Last

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, ubuntu-16.04

so I have a question where the answer could be very useful... How to take from X arg (like $3) to the last on the line ?

In Golang to do that it is like os.Args[3:] but we can use this for arrays too.

So the things I would like to do Is by using awk doing this (following the Golang Logic) :
`timedatectl timesync-status | awk 'NR==1 {print [$3:]}'`

expected result

`34min 8s (min: 32s; max 34min 8s);normal;4;2;91EECB0E;1us (-24);78.688ms (max: 5s);-50.923ms;103.234ms;25.637ms;70;-5,050ppm` (didn't take the server data because it is a concatenation excercise)

Comment: Please provide an example of the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$  timedatectl timesync-status | awk 'NR > 1 { t=substr($0,16); gsub(/[ ]+$/, "", t); printf "%s%s",s, t; s=";" } END { print "" }'
```

The `gsub` function is used to remove all the (unnecessary) trailing spaces that `timedatectl timesync-status` outputs.